# Can i story config in memory and use it in AWS Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have lambda function which listens to dynamo stream and process records for any update or insert in dynamo.

Currently this lambda code has list of variables which i want to convert to a config, since this list can change.

So i want my lambda function to read this list from a config, but i don't want any network call so i cant make call to s3/dynamo every time. i want this config stored locally in memory.

I want to initialize lambda and in this initialization read this config from table and store it in some variable and use it in every invocation.

Can i do this?

Comment: use elasticache service

Comment: Storing outside of Lambda (in DynamoDB or elsewhere) would be best, but you could also potentially store the config, if small, as environment variables of the Lambda function. Whenever the config changes, simply update those environment variables and that way the Lambda will always execute with the latest config, and it won't need to read anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you can't. Lambda is stateless - you can't count on anything you read into memory on one invocation to be available to the next invocation. You will need to store your config information somewhere, and read it back in each time.

Answer (score 2):

I have my lambda functions (nodejs) read *static* config files from a yaml file. You could do the same with a json file as needed. The app *also* reads dynamic data in from S3 at run time, noting that this is not what you want to do.

This means I was able to move the variables out of the code as hard-coded values, and have a separate config file that you can change pre-deployment with CI tools or such per environment. It also means you can exclude your config from your version control if needed.

The only downside is the config has to be uploaded with the lamda function when you deploy it, so it's available with the other lambda assets at run time. AFAIK you can't write back to a config during runtime.

You can see in the [project](https://github.com/lantrix/angryhuman-rss-generator) folder I have a `config.yml`. I'm using a nodejs module [node-yaml-config](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-yaml-config) to load into memory the config file each time the lambda is instantiated. It doesn't require any network call either.

[image: files in project]

In the config file I have all the params I need:

```yml
# Handler runtime config set
default:
  sourceRssUri: http://www.sourcerss.com/rss.php?key=abcd1234
  bucket: myappbucket
  region: us-east-1
  dataKey: data/rssdata
  dataOutKey: data/rssdata
  rssKey: myrss.xml
```

I load the config in at runtime, and then can reference any config items in my code by the key name. I just so happen to be using it for s3 operations here, you can do whatever.

```js
const yaml_config = require("node-yaml-config");
const config = yaml_config.load(__dirname + "/config.yml");

const aws = require("aws-sdk");
const bbpromise = require("bluebird");
const s3 = bbpromise.promisifyAll(new aws.S3({}));

var params = {
    Bucket: config.bucket,
    Key: config.dataOutKey,
    Body: JSON.stringify(feed.entries),
    ContentType: "application/json"
};
s3.putObjectAsync(params).catch(SyntaxError, function(e) {
    console.log("Error: ", e);
}).catch(function(e) {
    console.log("Catch: ", e);
});
```

This makes it super easy to add new configuration for the lambda handler, as anything I add to `config.yml` such as `myNewVariable` is now available to reference in the handler as `config.myNewVariable` without any new work.

It allows the config to change per environment, or before each deployment. The config is then loaded before the handler and stored locally in memory during the period of the lambda execution.

Comment: Amit Kumar no worries. If you think this answers, feel free to mark it as the answer.